# My whitelisting for secure navigiation is not working

Tags: php

Im doing a administrative panel, and Im trying to do a secure query string for navigation into my admin folder.

First in my login form page, if user login with sucess I store a session $result with admin information.

```
$result = $readUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$_SESSION['result'] = $result;
```

And then I have my admin dashboard.php file where I want to have my query string to do my navigation.

First, I see if session exist:

```
ob_start();
session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['result'])
{
    header('Location: index.php?restricted=true');
}
```

Then I have my query string:

```
echo '<div id="panel">';
if(empty($_GET['exe'])){
    require('home.php');
}
elseif(file_exists($_GET['exe'].'.php')){
    require($_GET['exe'].'.php');
}
else{
    require('404.php');
}
echo '</div><!-- /panel -->';
```

And my query string is working fine, but I want to add more security, and I read about whitelisting for this purpose.

And now Im trying to do my query string like this:

Im with this code below:

```
$whitelist = array('sis/home', 'sis/404', 'posts/index', 'posts/edit', 'categories/index', 'categories/edit', 'dashboard', 'inc/header.php','inc/footer.php');
if(empty($_GET['exe'])){
    require('sis/home.php');
}
elseif(in_array($_GET['exe'].'.php', $whitelist)){
    require($_GET['exe'].'.php');
}
else{
    require('sis/404.php');
}
```

But when I try to acess my url:

`http://localhost/adminPanel/admin/dashboard.php?exe=posts/index:`

I get always my 404.php file. And this is happening with all my navigation.

I'm just getting with success my home page:

`http://localhost/adminPanel/admin/dashboard.php`

My project folder organization is like this:

1 main folder "adminPanel", inside I have:

- 1 index.php file where I have my login form
- 1 dashobard.php file where Im doing my query string
- 1 folder "admin", inside admin folder I have:

  - 1 folder posts, inside I have one index.php file and one edit.php file
  - 1 folder includes, inside I have one footer.php file and one header.php file
  - 1 folder inc, inside I have one 404.php file and one home.php file

Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For a start, `in_array($_GET['exe'].'.php', $whitelist)` will never be `true` because the elements in your whitelist don't have `.php` at the end of them.

Comment: Thank you Shai, I think problem was really that! Now it seems that is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

Like [@Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1641835/shai) commented concatanating the '.php' will cause your in_array() to return false. Either remove the concat or add '.php' to every item in the array. First option would be better for performance.

In addition you might want to url encode your GET parameters.

```
http://localhost/adminPanel/admin/dashboard.php?exe=posts/index
```

To

```
http://localhost/adminPanel/admin/dashboard.php?exe=posts%2Findex
```

Last but not least you might also want to check if the file exist before you require it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Maarten. But can you explain me why is better to encode get parameters like you did with "%2F"?

Comment: See this paragraph on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding
TL;DR: forward slashes have a special meaning in URLs and might be misinterpreted.